# Looking for translation of "закладная втулка" (threaded bushing?)

Tags: terminology, molding

Sometimes we need a strong threaded joint in some part that is produced using molding. Say, this part itself is plastic. Then we design the part with a hole and insert there a.. "threaded bushing"? I don't know the proper name for this element in English. In Russian it is "закладная втулка" (insertable bushing/cylinder/etc - втулка/vtulka is a catch-all term for all things cylindrical that are used in an "axial manner" - something is inserted into them, or they are inserted somewhere, or both). I'm looking for a proper term in English.

I googled for **закладная втулка** and found this example relevant to my text:

> [image]

In the text that I'm translating into English, these brass insertable threaded elements in a plastic part produced using molding look like this:

> [image]

I found a DIN on [one Russian page](http://www.fastbolt.ru/din16903) describing "закладная втулка" and this DIN led me to English terms "[threaded bushing](https://www.linn-praezision.de/en/products/din-16903.html)", "threaded insert". Are these okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As they are going into blind holes, then threaded insert would be better.

Comment: Would we use the term "threaded bushing" for inserts that pass through the item (have holes both sides of the item)?

Comment: For me, a bush is not threaded... it is a type of bearing...

Comment: The top picture you show are blind nuts or domed nuts

Comment: @SolarMike "For me, a bush is not threaded... it is a type of bearing" Fastener suppliers don't agree with that. See google for lots of examples.

Comment: @alephzero  Don't just send people off to google, please.  Post a link to one of those "lots of examples" from google.  Post the keywords which you've used to find that.

Comment: @CopperKettle  I concur with Mike that bushing is a bearing surface (подшипник скольжения).  The only thing that comes to mind if someone says "threaded bushing" is a part that has threads on the outside and a smooth cylindrical surface on the inside.  That's not the case with the parts in the O.P.

Answer (score 4):

This is called "*threaded insert*" in English.

For more context, here are product page for threaded inserts for plastic: [this](https://www.pemnet.com/fastening-products/si-inserts-for-plastic/) and [this](https://www.stanleyengineeredfastening.com/fasteners/inserts/heat-ultrasonic-inserts/dodge-ultrasert-iv-flanged).  Both of are major manufacturers based in US.

Additional examples of plastic parts with threaded inserts: [this](https://www.flickr.com/photos/46038819@N07/15722721032) and [this](https://www.flickr.com/photos/46038819@N07/22177155596).